# logo image path not working for pages with parameter

Tags: laravel

images of header are getting parameter added with their original path while calling at the pages (having parameters )

My code is :

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}"><img src="{{ $general->website_logo?? 'Not Found' }}" 
class="img-fluid" alt="logo"></a>
```

It works nicely for normal pages (without params ) but , when called from pages with params , the images get disappeared :

[image]

Comment: can you `inspect element` on logo image? maybe image using relative path.

Comment: what does ``$general->website_logo`` contains?

Comment: Got the answer guys - thanks for your time. Using "asset" solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using laravel assets, use {{asset('')}}, so it can work in everypage, in the method that u use it counts the param's as files, when you use the {{asset('')}} it gonna work perfectly on all pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot completely since I was working on some other part for long time